# SQLAlchemy - Multithreaded Persistent Object Creation, how to merge back into single session to avoid state conflict?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have tens (potentially hundreds) of thousands of persistent objects that I want to generate in a multithreaded fashion due the processing required.

While the creation of the objects happens in separate threads (using Flask-SQLAlchemy extension btw with scoped sessions) the call to write the generated objects to the DB happens in 1 place after the generation has completed.

The problem, I believe, is that the objects being created are part of several existing relationships-- thereby triggering the automatic addition to the identity map despite being created in separate, concurrent, threads with no explicit session in any of the threads.

I was hoping to contain the generated objects in a single list, and then write the whole list (using a single session object) to the database. This results in an error like this:

```
AssertionError: A conflicting state is already present in the identity map for key (<class 'app.ModelObject'>, (1L,))
```

Hence why I believe the identity map has already been populated, because it's when I try to add and commit using the global session **outside** of the concurrent code, the assertion error is triggered.

The final detail is that whatever session object(s), (scoped or otherwise, as I don't fully understand how automatic addition to the identity map works in the case of multithreading) I cannot find a way / don't know how to get a reference to them so that even if I wanted to deal with a separate session per process I could.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. The only reason I am not posting code (yet) is because it's difficult to abstract a working example immediately out of my app. I will post if somebody really needs to see it though.

Comment: my understanding of flask-sqlalchemy is that it assigns sessions not on a thread-local basis but on a per-request basis.  But i dont understand really how it is you're running a multithreaded task in the context of...a web request?   this entirely depends on your session creation/usage pattern which is not clear here.

Comment: Let me clarify. This particular code is being run from the CLI outside of Flask's request context. My concern is that the model classes are still using the declarative base created by Flask-SQLAlchemy, and since the generated objects are children, they are being automatically added to the identity map when they are created and associated with their parent objects (that are already persistent) The CLI script is never passed any explicit session reference, which is why I am not sure how to handle the conflict that is occuring. I can only assume each thread is creating one on the fly.

Comment: I'm going to abstract and upload some example code in about an hour

Comment: Hey, thanks for giving this question some attention. Ultimately it was the thoroughness of your documentation that helped me come up with a solution :)

Comment: The detached state hypothesis is actually the missing detail I'd like to clarify here. Because the objects are being associated with parent objects that are already persisted (in an active session), are the child objects (within the child processes) truly detached or are they transient / pending somehow because of the association?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each session is thread-local; in other words there is a separate session for each thread.  If you decide to pass some instances to another thread, they will become "detached" from the session.  Use `db.session.add_all(objects)` in the receiving thread to put them all back.

For some reason, it looks like you're creating objects with the same identity (primary key columns) in different threads, then trying to send them both to the database.  One option is to fix why this is happening, so that identities will be guaranteed unique.  You may also try [merging](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#merging); `merged_object = db.session.merge(other_object, load=False)`.

*Edit: zzzeek's comment clued me in on something else that may be going on:*

With Flask-SQLAlchemy, the session is tied to the app context.  Since that is thread local, spawning a new thread will invalidate the context; there will be no database session in the threads.  All the instances are detached there, and cannot properly track relationships.  One solution is to pass `app` to each thread and perform everything within a `with app.app_context():` block.  Inside the block, first use `db.session.add` to populate the local session with the passed instances.  You should still merge in the master task afterwards to ensure consistency.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to clarify the problem and the solution with some pseudo-code in case somebody has this problem / wants to do this in the future.

```
class ObjA(object):
    obj_c = relationship('ObjC', backref='obj_c')

class ObjB(object):
    obj_c = relationship('ObjC', backref='obj_c')

class ObjC(object):
    obj_a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('obj_a.id'))
    obj_b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('obj_b.id'))

    def __init__(self, obj_a, obj_b):
        self.obj_a = obj_a
        self.obj_b = obj_b


def make_a_bunch_of_c(obj_a, list_of_b=None):
    return [ObjC(obj_a, obj_b) for obj_b in list_of_b]

def parallel_generate():
   list_of_a = session.query(ObjA).all() # assume there are 1000 of these
   list_of_b = session.query(ObjB).all() # and 30 of these

   fxn = functools.partial(make_a_bunch_of_c, list_of_b=list_of_b)
   pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
   all_the_things = pool.map(fxn, list_of_a)
   return all_the_things
```

Now let's stop here a second. The original problem was that attempting to ADD the list of ObjC's caused the error message in the original question:

```
session.add_all(all_the_things)

AssertionError: A conflicting state is already present in the identity map for key [...]
```

Note: The error occurs during the adding phase, the commit attempt never even happens because the assertion occurs pre-commit. As far as I could tell.

Solution:

```
all_the_things = parallel_generate()
for thing in all_the_things:
    session.merge(thing)
session.commit()
```

The details of session utilization when dealing with automatically added objects (via the relationship cascading) is still beyond me and I cannot explain why the conflict originally occurred. All I know is that using the merge function will cause SQLAlchemy to sort all of the child objects that were created across 10 different processes into a single session in the master process.

I would be curious in the why, if anyone happens across this.